# Sobject Get on Relationship fields : Invalid Field

Tags: apex, sobject

I am working on a module where I have to create complex nested JSON dynamically based upon configs stored in custom metadata, The metadata contains Object name, fields names as text fields.

Now the problem I am facing is I can't use Sobject get on relationship fields, it gives runtime error.

Minimum viable code to reproduce:

```
Opportunity opp = [Select id,Account.Name from Opportunity Limit 1][0];
opp.get('Account.Name');
```

Exception:

> Error on line 2, column 1: System.SObjectException: Invalid field
>   Account.Name for Opportunity AnonymousBlock: line 2, column 1

How can I dynamically access relationship fields using Sobject get?

Comment: There are a bunch of patterns out there for this issue. I added those easiest for me to find, but I imagine there are others as well. You could also look at a class like [FieldReference](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector/blob/master/src/classes/FieldReference.cls), which would allow you to do `FieldReference.build('Account.Name').getFrom(opp)`.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson, thats what I wanted. Never investigated there would be getSObject(fieldName) method.